# Animating SVG group object using the JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg

I created a SVG group-object and appended rectangle and foreignObject-SVG element containing HTML text. I defined an animation function which is called on the 'mousedown' event on the group. The animation function makes a transition on the element specified by an id.

Which is the part that does not work. If I use :

```
d3.select("#group").transition()
```

I can see the x-coordinates of the group changing but the elements inside the group do not move. If I set the #Id to the Id of the foreignObject or the rectangle they will move. So I assume I have to call the transition on "every subelement of the group" and I do not know how to do it.

Here is an example I prepared : http://jsfiddle.net/YxfMH/

I also wonder how can I drag the "whole group" around with the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVG [`<g>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups) elements don't have x or y attributes. You can set such things just like you could set an attribute called 'foo' but it won't have any effect. If you want to move a group then you need to set a translate transform on it e.g. transform="translate(10, 10)"

```
// Add a group to the canvas
var group = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "group")
    .attr("transform", "translate(10, 10)")
    .on("mousedown", animate);
```

and

```
function animate() {
    d3.select("#group").transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", "translate(100, 100)")
};
```

are the bits you need to change to get [this...](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/YxfMH/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. But how can I set the translate() arguments using variables if the value is defined as string ? And how can I get the actual position of the group ?

Comment: keep the x and y components in variables and then construct the appropriate string.

Comment: In regards to making it easier to build the string, I often have a simple function like `var translate = function(x,y){ return "translate("+x+", "+y+")"}` so I can just call `translate(x,100);`.. saves typing all those quotes and plusses all the time!

Comment: Oh! That is a nice idea! I think that would allow to implement the "dragging" easier, I am goinf to try this.
But anyhow, how can I get the translate-values (the coordinates) ? I am forceds to do some string-splitting/parsing or is there an nice way ?

Answer (score 0):

you can access direct to the matrix of a svg element to change the position or rotation

look this example "[U.F.O animation](http://www.janvas.com/illustrators_designers_developers/projects/janvas2D_web/examples_EN.php?exampleName=ufo_animation_EN)"

http://www.janvas.com/illustrators_designers_developers/projects/janvas2D_web/examples_EN.php?exampleName=ufo_animation_EN