# Which framework allows us to animate the g tag in svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, velocity.js

g tag receives it's own animate tag for certain animations. But it seems quite limited to be used for advanced animations. We have jQuery animate for animation which is quite useful, but we cannot exclusively use it to animate the g tag due to again, limitations. I would like to ask what other options do I have to animate the g tag assuming that it has some `id` or `classname` set to it. In `snap.svg` one can make use of the `svg` image and interpret it. I don't want to use that however. I prefer using the `svg` tag and keeping things simpler. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/9aogt124/) where I want to apply animation to the cube. I am open to any frameworks, but just wanna know if this is possible and a normal method to be implemented. If yes, I would highly appreciate an answer with reference links and/or a sample code to properly implement the same. I have searched `SO` before asking this. Here is the code sample. I am not looking for CSS3 animations and transitions since **IE9+** is a must.

**SVG**

```
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="cube">
<path id="f1" d="M190,200L260,160L330,200L260,240L190,200"></path>
<path id="f2" d="M260,240L330,200L330,280L260,320L260,240"></path>
<path id="f3" d="M260,240L260,320L190,280L190,200L260,240"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: have you use `animateMotion` tag for svg??

Comment: What kind of animations are you looking at? Did you try d3?

Comment: Moving the cube, rotating it, fading it in.. Simple stuffs like that. I am open to any frameworks with less complexity and cleaner implementation. The movement might occur after a timeout -- hope you get it now.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15934263/2370599 Or perhaps this? https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-group-element-and-d3js

Comment: Here is the kind of animation that I am looking for http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/s0wgc884/ , But this I have made using `raphael`. But I want to make use of `svg's` g tag where I get better `css` and `js` control. I want to restrict the use of framework to the bare minimum while still making use of what it can offer. So `d3` it is?

Comment: I think I've given you the complete solution right @ThomasSebastian??

Comment: Yes you did @GuruprasadRao and I thank you a lot for that. But I am searching if there are better methods for the same. I am sure there are.

Comment: Yea there are!! But you need to search alot @ThomasSebastian.. :)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "svg image", both snap.svg and Velocity allow you to animate the g tag. Just read the docs (: